# What I'm doing wrong with Emscripten preload-file?

Tags: javascript, sdl-2, emscripten

I have dirs structure like this:

```
workfolder\
  l4\
    font\
      Roboto-Black.ttf
    sdl_font.c
```

When I tried to make HTML file with this command

```
emcc l4/sdl_font.c --emrun --preload-file l4/font -s USE_SDL=2 -s USE_SDL_TTF=2 -o bin/sdl_font.html
```

I got this error:

```
cache:INFO: generating port: sysroot\lib\wasm32-emscripten\libharfbuzz.a... (this will be cached in "E:\prog\emsdk\upstream\emscripten\cache\sysroot\lib\wasm32-emscripten\libharfbuzz.a" for subsequent builds)
root:INFO: building port: harfbuzz
configure: cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -BE:\prog\emsdk\upstream\emscripten\cache\ports-builds\harfbuzz -HE:\prog\emsdk\upstream\emscripten\cache\ports\harfbuzz\harfbuzz-1.7.5 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=E:\prog\emsdk\upstream\emscripten\cache\ports-builds\harfbuzz -DFREETYPE_INCLUDE_DIRS=E:\prog\emsdk\upstream\emscripten\cache\sysroot\include\freetype2\freetype;E:\prog\emsdk\upstream\emscripten\cache\sysroot\include\freetype2\freetype\config -DFREETYPE_LIBRARY=E:\prog\emsdk\upstream\emscripten\cache\sysroot\lib\wasm32-emscripten\libfreetype.a -DHB_HAVE_FREETYPE=ON
-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=E:\prog\emsdk\upstream\emscripten\cmake\Modules\Platform\Emscripten.cmake -DCMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING_EMULATOR="E:/prog/emsdk/node/14.15.5_64bit/bin/node.exe"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\prog\emsdk\upstream\emscripten\emcc.py", line 3317, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "E:\prog\emsdk\upstream\emscripten\emcc.py", line 3310, in main
    ret = run(args)
  File "E:\prog\emsdk\upstream\emscripten\emcc.py", line 1953, in run
    system_libs.add_ports_cflags(cflags, shared.Settings)
  File "E:\prog\emsdk\upstream\emscripten\tools\system_libs.py", line 1855, in add_ports_cflags
    port.get(Ports, settings, shared)
  File "E:\prog\emsdk\upstream\emscripten\tools\ports\harfbuzz.py", line 71, in get
    return [shared.Cache.get_lib(get_lib_name(settings), create, what='port')]
  File "E:\prog\emsdk\upstream\emscripten\tools\cache.py", line 130, in get_lib
    return self.get(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\prog\emsdk\upstream\emscripten\tools\cache.py", line 158, in get
    creator(cachename)
  File "E:\prog\emsdk\upstream\emscripten\tools\ports\harfbuzz.py", line 64, in create
    building.configure(configure_args)
  File "E:\prog\emsdk\upstream\emscripten\tools\building.py", line 326, in configure
    run_process(args, stdout=stdout, stderr=stderr, env=env, **kwargs)
  File "E:\prog\emsdk\upstream\emscripten\tools\shared.py", line 96, in run_process
    ret = subprocess.run(cmd, check=check, input=input, *args, **kw)
  File "E:\prog\zzmal\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 505, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "E:\prog\zzmal\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "E:\prog\zzmal\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1420, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл (File not found)
```

I tried to change some arguments or paths but I still get this error.

Comment: p.s. I am using windows 10.

Comment: Well, I tested command on hello.cpp from emscripten guide, so file_packer not cause of this error. Most likely it cannot load or use SDL2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this exact issue as well. This is due to Harfbuzz library which is now a dependency for SDL_ttf. Harfbuzz requires `make` to be installed. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/issues/13648) on emscripten Github which suggests several workarounds:

1. Wait for version 2.0.16
2. modify tools/ports/harfbuzz.py locally with the patch from [#13655](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/pull/13655)
3. Install make on your Windows machine